# Joining 3 three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have this diagram which should explain my situation I need some help on joining 3 tables which I have no idea how to do this kind of thing:

[image]

So I can go through a while loop of retrieving the records by doing this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" alt="" />

Album: <?php echo $row['album_name']; ?> 
AlbumID: <?php echo $row['album_id']; ?>
```

Comment: Are you asking for SQL syntax or advice on whether a join is the right operation, or what?

Comment: A SQL syntax is useful since I can join 2 tables at once. But 3 is what I cannot do. This is not homework for whoever retagged my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) will prevent returning albums that don't have images. The [ORDER BY ... DESC](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) will sort the results in descending order but I'm not sure how to only return the last record. It would take some sort of combination of ORDER BY, [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [TOP](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp), perhaps.

```
SELECT 
    album_table.album_id, 
    album_table.album_name, 
    images_table.filename
FROM album_table
INNER JOIN images_table ON images_table.album_id = album_table.album_id
WHERE album_table.user_id = uid
ORDER BY images_table.date DESC
```

Comment: @markus: I meant to write INNER JOIN! (edited to fix this). The LEFT JOIN would be useful to return albums even when there is no associated image.

Comment: This is the SQL syntax I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @lolwut: If you figure out the syntax for returning only the **last** image, please let us know.

Comment: The syntax works perfect, even if an album hasn't been assigned an image it will return `NULL` that can replaced with dummy image. But it's great. :)

Comment: I'd also like to say that if you add `GROUP BY album_table.album_id` will prevent duplicates since I just experienced duplicates that related to the `album_id` so using the `GROUP BY` will slim down the duplicates from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an `INNER JOIN` is what you are looking for

This site gives a good example

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: many people on Stack Overflow don't like w3schools, I found out the hard way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware. It's not a great source however for many simple things it provides easy to read examples.

I think the biggest problem with w3schools is it's out of date HTML/CSS sections, not the MySQL page.

Answer (score 0):

@lolwut: Try --

```
SELECT 
  album_table.album_id, album_table.album_name, images_table.filename 
FROM album_table 
  INNER JOIN images_table ON images_table.album_id = album_table.album_id
  INNER JOIN users_table ON users_table.uid = album_table.user_id
WHERE (users_table.uid = ' . $uid . ') 
ORDER BY images_table.date DESC
```

`$uid` should be the currently logged in user's session...or you can leave that `WHERE` clause out entirely if you want to return all users' info.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in this case you only need to join two tables (as a general rule of thumb, the fewer joins you do, the better).

Since you know the User ID, you can query that directly off of the album table name.

If your users_table happened to have another column "user_name",  and you wanted to search of that, then you would need to join to the users table.

```
SELECT filename, album_name, album_id
FROM album_table at, images_table it
AND at.album_id = it.album_id
AND at.user_id = $user_id
```

Comment: Why do you write your query without explicit join?