# Joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

First off, sorry if this is a near enough duplicate. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396717/joining-3-three-tables), which nearly does what I want, but I couldn't wrap my head around how to alter it to my needs.

I've got these 3 tables:

```
cs_Accounts:

+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
| id | email                       | username    |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
| 63 | jamasawaffles@googlil.com   | jamwaffles2 |
| 64 | jamwghghhfles@goomail.com   | jamwaffles3 |
| 65 | dhenddfggdfgetal-pipdfg.com | dhendu9411  |
| 60 | jwapldfgddfgfffles.co.uk    | jamwaffles  |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+

cs_Groups:

+----+-----------+------------+-------------+
| id | low_limit | high_limit | name        |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |         0 |          0 | admin       |
|  2 |         1 |         50 | developer   |
|  3 |        76 |        100 | reviewer    |
|  4 |        51 |         75 | beta tester |
|  5 |         1 |         50 | contributor |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+

cs_Permissions:

+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | group_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  4 |      60 |        4 |
|  3 |      60 |        1 |
|  5 |      60 |        2 |
|  6 |      62 |        1 |
|  7 |      62 |        3 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

I've been wrestling with a 3 way join for hours now, and I can't get the results I want. I'm looking for this behaviour: a row will be returned for every user from `cs_Accounts` where there is a row in `cs_Permissions` that contains their ID and the ID of a group from `cs_Groups`, as well as the group with the `group_id` has a `high_lmiit` and `low_limit` in a range I can specify.

Using the data in the tables above, we might end up with something like this:

```
email                         username      cs_Groups.name
----------------------------------------------------------
jwapldfgddfgfffles.co.uk      jamwaffles    admin
jwapldfgddfgfffles.co.uk      jamwaffles    developer
jwapldfgddfgfffles.co.uk      jamwaffles    beta tester
dhenddfggdfgetal-pipdfg.com   dhendu9411    admin
dhenddfggdfgetal-pipdfg.com   dhendu9411    reviewer
```

There is an extra condition, however. This condition is where rows are only selected if the group the user belongs to has a `high_limit` and `low_limit` with values I can specify using a `WHERE` clause. As you can see, the table above only contains users with rows in the permissions table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feels a lot like homework but with a name like James I'm always willing to help.

```
select a.email,a.username,g.name
from cs_Accounts a
inner join cs_Permissions p on p.user_id = a.id
inner join cs_Groups g on g.id = p.Group_id
where g.low_limit > 70
and g.high_limt < 120
```

Comment: This is actually part of a project I'm working on. I can see why this might be homework, but it's not - just a very confusing problem!

Comment: Thank you good sir - this works a treat :-) I didn't realise it would be quite as simple as this!

Comment: awesome answer, adapted this structure to fit my query and it worked straight off, intuitive to say the least! reputation++ :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the query

```
SELECT ac.email, ac.username, gr.name 
FROM cs_Accounts AS ac 
LEFT JOIN cs_Permissions AS per ON per.user_id = ac.id 
INNER JOIN cs_Groups AS gr ON per.user_id = gr.id
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause to this query if you want